# Informatica report query

Tags: informatica

Please find the below requirement,i tried with route and a sort and aggregator but amnt getting the actual output

Source records

```
ID   type   amount desc
1    Credit 300         xyz
2    Debit  100         abc
1    Credit 400         xyz
1    Debit  500          xyz
1    Debit  200          xyz
2     Credit 200         abc
```

Result

```
1  Credit  300   xyz
1  Credit  400   xyz
1 Debit    700           ( total of 1 credit & des is null) 
1 Debit    500   abc
1 Debit    200   abc
1 Credit   700  
2 Credit   200   abc
2 Debit    200
2  Debit  100   abc
2  Credit 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mapping with 2 branches:

- The first branch simply passes the records without any change to data
- The second branch aggregates amounts grouping by ID and Type

You can then put a Union to get all records together, then a Sorter on the same keys, ID and Type, to get data in the right order for the Target.

The mapping would look like this:

```
Source -> Expression -> Union -> Sorter -> Target
      +-> Aggregator --^
```

Comment: Probably need an expression to convert Debit to Credit and vice versa on the incoming type but overall the right approach. Still scratching my head to the ask... why would you want to autogenerate your matching book entry... goes against fundamental accounting practise